# OpenOCD throws "JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes" error

Tags: raspberry-pi, jtag, error, modem, openocd

I am trying to install openWRT on a router using my Raspberry Pi Zero. I am following the exact steps as explained in http://www.alfredklomp.com/technology/experia-v8/
However, for some reason I keep getting the following errors:

```
Warn : gpio 11 is already exported
Warn : gpio 25 is already exported

Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes
```

Full output:

```
    Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-01242-g11c5efd2-dirty (2020-05-15-17:51)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter srst delay' not 'adapter_nsrst_delay'
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "jtag". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
force hard breakpoints
flash_file
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : SysfsGPIO JTAG/SWD bitbang driver
Info : JTAG and SWD modes enabled
Warn : gpio 11 is already exported
Warn : gpio 25 is already exported
Info : This adapter doesn't support configurable speed
Error: JTAG scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes
Error: Check JTAG interface, timings, target power, etc.
Error: Trying to use configured scan chain anyway...
Error: vrx200.cpu0: IR capture error; saw 0x00 not 0x01
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Info : starting gdb server for vrx200.cpu1 on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong? I have been searching for ages, but this is my first time doing this and I am not finding anything useful. 
Thanks for taking the time to look at my issue! I really appreciate it :)

I am thinking the connections might be incorrect, but I am doing the exact same as described by him and I used both his schematics plus the image to match his wire placing.

Comment: "scan chain interrogation failed: all zeroes" could happen if the target device is powered down.  But it could also happen if the "gpio XX is already exported" warnings mean that the JTAG pins aren't really connected to anything on the debug device side.

Comment: So that could mean that for some reason the pins I connected them to aren't for any specific purpose? Can I break either the debug device or the pi if I wrongly connect the cables? Otherwise I could try different ways of connecting them. As I have seen different JTAG 14-pin layouts on the internet, but I figured since this is the exact same device as in the link, this should be right. Would that be a dumb thing to do?

Comment: The "warning GPIO already exported" makes me think that you've already got something assigned to those pins. Are you running any kind of drivers or overlays? What does your boot.txt look like?

Comment: Alternatively you could open the openocd configuration file and pick two other unused pins in place of 11 and 25.

Comment: @RonBeyer interesting... I tried to run openocd with nothing attached to my pins in order to check what would happen. Indeed the GPIO 11 & 25 are still "already exported". I normally dont really use my pi for this cause and have only gotten the pins installed yesterday, I therefore dont think it is a driver issue (I hope). Additionally I have been trying to track down the boot.txt file but haven't found it yet. Ill let you know what's  in there when I find it. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @RonBeyer I got this when trying to check if the pins are in use:
`sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
gpiochip0: GPIOs 0-53, parent: platform/20200000.gpio, pinctrl-bcm2835:
 gpio-18  (                    |sysfs               ) in  lo
 gpio-47  (                    |led0                ) out lo
`

I also tried:
`echo 25 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport`
`echo 11 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport`
They both throw an error, `write error: Invalid argument` although pin 18 for example doesnt throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have gotten rid of the errors for me

1. Go to the config file for the raspberry pi interface, this is most likely located in:

> ```
> /usr/share/openocd/scripts/interface/sysfsgpio-raspberrypi.cfg
> ```

2. Add

> sysfsgpio_srst_num 7

3. Save the file, it should run now

*EDITED: Edited because of comment that the original way wasn't the way to go*

Comment: This is all but certainly not the correct thing to do and may be leading to your newer failure.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you for digging a bit deeper into my posts. Why wouldnt this be correct? It seems to be the only way in which I was able to prevent gpio 11 and 25 of already being exported. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I removed that line as I figured the swd method interfered with the jtag method

Comment: Already exported is **not an error**.  It's just telling you that those pins are still gpios after a previous attempt to run the program, which is a non-issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton alright, thank you! I'm going to try and see if it will run like that tomorrow! I really appreciate your time and effort helping me with this! :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Unfortunately it is giving the same error as before,  I'll keep digging